# SQL combine two columns and pick max time beetwen consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to combine two columns eg. OnDateTime and OffDateTime.

```
OnDateTime               OffDateTime
2016-05-16 13:47:22.987 2016-05-16 13:47:22.987
2016-05-16 13:47:26.347 2016-05-16 13:47:26.347
2016-05-16 13:47:27.643 2016-05-16 13:47:27.643
2016-05-16 13:48:08.003 2016-05-17 13:48:08.003
2016-05-16 13:48:10.410 2016-08-24 13:48:10.410
2016-05-16 13:48:11.913 2016-08-24 13:48:11.913
2016-05-16 13:50:09.090 2019-02-09 13:50:09.090
```

I would like to combine this two column at one eg. Time, then order by DESC and count max time beetwen consecutive rows (1 and 2, 2 and 3 ....).
Thanks for any help!

Comment: what should the result look like?

Comment: It colud be one value, it must by the longest period.

Comment: So you wanna find row with highest DateDiff?

Comment: Can you add to your question what the output would look like given the example data.

Comment: Not clear what "max time between two consecutive rows" means... Please elaborate.

Comment: What does "max time between consecutive rows" mean?

Comment: Well, yes but first combine two columns and find the longest time beetwen eg. 1 and 2 rows, 2 and 3 rows and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want ??

```
Select Max(DateDiff(second, a.OffDateTime, b.OnDateTime))
From table a
   join table b
       on b.OnDateTime =
            (Select Min(OnDateTime)
             From table
             where OnDateTime > a.OffDateTime)
```

Explanation:

Join finds, for each row in Table a, the next consecutive row in the table (as b), then max() function finds the greatest interval between end of row a and start of row b

Answer (score -1):

Concat + substract the dates it will give difference in days. Multiply with 24 to get value in hours, and so on..

> select concat(date1 , date2) Dates, (date1 - date2) Diff from table;

use the Max to get the max row.

Comment: The word combine used in the question made me think of concat. if not useful then remove. simple.

Comment: Lol. I know. My mistake. Should not always trust on words what people say/write. :)